# php multi dimensional array unique

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, unique

I am facing Problem with removing the duplicate value from the multidimensional array.

```
 Array
 (
    [524] => Array
        (
            [0] => 526
            [1] => 530
            [2] => 528
            [3] => 528
        )

    [1100] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1126
            [1] => 1126
            [2] => 1126
            [3] => 1126
        )

    [1244] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1260
            [1] => 1266
            [2] => 1260
            [3] => 1260
        )

)
```

there are duplicates value in array. i want to remove them.

**Needed Output will be**

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [524] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 526
>             [1] => 530
>             [2] => 528
>         )
>
>     [1100] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 1126
>         )
>
>     [1244] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 1260
>             [1] => 1266
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: do :- `foreach($array  as &$arr){ $arr = array_unique($arr);}print_r($array);`:- https://3v4l.org/lBZJB

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($a as $k => &$v){
  $v = array_unique($v);
}
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/93LGY

Comment: Please don't answer "Gimme code"-type questions. Answering them will just keep the OP and future visitors to keep asking.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson noted.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar  much better approach:-`foreach($array as &$arr){ $arr = array_unique($arr);}print_r($array);`:- https://3v4l.org/lBZJB